# Multi-threaded Rendering in OpenGL

Tags: multithreading, opengl, directx, rendering

Is this even possible? Im learning DirectX atm and am trying to apply some of what i've learnt to OpenGL.

I know you can have multi-threaded rendering in DirectX using deferred contexts, but i didnt think OpenGL had this support, i've found examples of multithreading in OpenGL but not multithreaded rendering which is what im trying to find out; or maybe i've mis-understood the difference?

If it is possible, could anyone provide some basic code for me as an example.

Comment: Just use asynchronous uploads.. also: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd gain from MT rendering.  AFAIK, D3D and OpenGL must eventually serialise commands down to a single thread at the driver level.  I imagine MT rendering just severely complicates the issue.

Comment: "I know you can have multi-threaded rendering in DirectX using deferred contexts" That isn't multithreaded rendering. That's simply storing some rendering commands and playing them back.

Comment: The idea behind deferred contexts is that the driver work can be split across multiple CPU cores. Even if the instructions are eventually sent to the GPU sequentially, this could still be a performance gain if you were CPU limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL doesn't have an equivalent to D3D11's Deferred Contexts. The closest thing to that would be display lists, but these solve an entirely different problem and are very much not meant to be rebuilt over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer to the OPs question, but it is of importance to his request:

The GPU is somewhat like a mutually exclusive resource. If you have multiple threads performing drawing operations you're generating management overhead. The work has to split up to shader units or some timeslicing is involved. Either way, if the drawing operations go to the same framebuffer the operations must be synchronized, which means the GPU pipelines get stalled quite oftenly.

The net result is, that performing multithreaded operation on a GPU will most likely result in largely reduced performance.

Also there's no need to do multithreaded operation on a GPU to parallelize the work. This already happens by single drawing operations being split up to the GPUs individual shader units.

Comment: It should be added that OpenGL drivers are notoriously single threaded so commands will probably end up in the same command queue anyway. Possibly the single useful case for multiple contexts is to take advantage of DMA/Copy Engines for truly asynchronous IO

Comment: @itzJanuary: Multithreaded operation within OpenGL drivers has improved a lot in the past years, but there are still a lot of global locks all around. After all it's a big state machine and by sharing resources between contexts active of different threads you trigger lots of locks. Vulkan is far better suited for multithreading, but even in Vulkan some things will end up in a single thread.